# Ldap Authentication before print with cups

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap, cups

I configured cups in my ubuntu server.

I have LDAP server with 250+ users.

Before any print job, it will ask for authentication (from LDAP server) of users. and after successful authentication print job should complete.

How to do it.. ?

what changes I have to do in my cups config .. ?

Comment: There are a lot of hits when googling for "cups ldap" that appear to deal with that field. All those did not help?

Comment: it works when accessing the LDAP server. I want users should authenticate from LDAP before print any document